# jquery DataTables undefine

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with Individual column searching (select inputs) using jquery dataTable

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tblDemo').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });
            column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + $(d).text().trim() + '">' + $(d).text().trim() + '</option>')
            });
        });
    },
    orderCellsTop: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    ordering: false,
    lengthChange: false,
});
});
```

I am facing problem that DataTables search not working with 
It come up with **dataTable undefine** at

```
$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
    $(this).val()
);
```

this line 
Please help me for solution

Comment: Does it matter that you have `DataTable` and then `dataTable`? Notice capitals - haven't used it enough, hence just a comment

Comment: check your jquery.dataTables is loaded properly or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, your script runs, when the document is not fully ready.
Try to wrap your code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: it is there only , that is not issue

Comment: Can you share full source code? I will try to find the problem. If not - try logging the value of $, $.fn

Answer (score -1):

if u use jquery add this script in head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is there only, that is not an issue